# is there a way in paper.js to zoom just a part of the canvas instead of the whole?

Tags: canvas, zooming, scale, paperjs

I am building a Webtool with two sections inside the canvas:

- The first section is for selecting paths.
- the second section is for placing this paths (writing with them)

I am using paper.js for all the functions inside the canvas. I made two layers for the different Sections and switch between them by tracking the mouse position.

Now i want to implement a zoom on the first section. I saw that the view object in paper.js comes with a zoom function. After some googling I found this https://gist.github.com/ryascl/4c1fd9e2d5d0030ba429 solution for a simple zoom.

Now my problem; if i use this zoom the whole canvas gets zoomed in/out. This is not what I need. I need the zoom only on the first section. Is there a way to zoom just a certain area, or maybe a certain layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 possible solutions for this problem:

#### solution 1

You can directly scale your items by using [item.scale()](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#scale-scale) instead of using [view.zoom](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#zoom).
The problem that you might encounter is that your layer will certainly overlap so you could combine this approach with [group.clipped](http://paperjs.org/reference/group/#clipped) to mask your layer overflow.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating this solution.

```
// Draw a line materializing layers separation.
new Path.Line({
    from: view.bounds.topCenter,
    to: view.bounds.bottomCenter,
    strokeColor: 'black'
});

// Draw a rectangle that will be used to crop the layer.
var cropRectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
    from: view.bounds.toLeft,
    to: view.bounds.bottomCenter
});

// Draw a circle in the left part of the screen.
var circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: [view.bounds.leftCenter.x + view.center.x / 2, view.center.y],
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

// Create a group that will be used to pan/zoom left part.
var group = new Group([circle]);

// Create left part layer and crop it with the rectangle so that overflow is
// hidden.
var layer = new Layer([cropRectangle, group]);
layer.clipped = true;

// Directly manipulate the group when you want to pan/zoom.
group.translate(view.bounds.width / 4, 0);
group.scale(1.5);

// You can use the same architecture for the right part...
```

#### solution 2

Personally, I would go with another solution consisting of managing 2 separated canvas, initializing `Paper.js` on each one to produce 2 distinct [PaperScope](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/) instances.
Then you will be able to control `view.zoom` for each of those canvases.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsbf0p43/) demonstrating this solution.

```
// Initialize paper scopes.
var scope1 = new paper.PaperScope();
scope1.setup(document.getElementById('canvas1'));

var scope2 = new paper.PaperScope();
scope2.setup(document.getElementById('canvas2'));

// Draw a circle on left canvas.
new paper.Path.Circle({
    center: scope1.view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    parent: scope1.project.activeLayer
});

// Draw a circle on right canvas.
new paper.Path.Circle({
    center: scope2.view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'blue',
    parent: scope2.project.activeLayer
});

// Zoom in left canvas.
scope1.view.zoom = 2;

// Zoom out right canvas.
scope2.view.zoom = 0.5;
```